# React Native cannot update State Hook with data from AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

Hello im currently learning AsyncStorage in react native.
so i write some state like this

```
const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [id, setId] = useState(null)
```

i set it null because i want to get the id from AsyncStorage, so i write a simple function to get and set the value  like this :

```
async function getAsyncStorageId(){
  const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id')
  console.log('user id from AsyncStorage is: ',userId)
  setId(userId)
  console.log('state hooks id : ',id)
}
```

and i put it into useEffect Hooks

```
 useEffect(()=>{
  getAsyncStorageId()
 },[])
```

so i test my code the id state wont update it stay null, but the console.log(userId) have an id value.

```
user id from AsyncStorage is:  6
state hooks id :  null
```

i dont know why i cant set the state with value from the asyncstorage

=======================
*edit : this is the code that i used to set the id in AsyncStorage.
i put this code in my Login Screen, so when the user succesfully login i store the id, username, token, and role in async storage

```
const login = async () => {
try {
  let response = await axios.post(`${url}/users/login`, {
    email: props.email,
    password: props.password,
  });
  let loginData = response.data;
  console.log(loginData,'sukses login')
  setAsyncStorage('token',loginData.token)
  loginData.name === null ? setAsyncStorage('name', 'pengguna') : setAsyncStorage('name',loginData.name)
  setAsyncStorage('role', loginData.role)
  setAsyncStorage('id', loginData.id)

  props.navigation.navigate("Artikel",{
    id:loginData.id,
    token:loginData.token,
    name:loginData.name
  })

} catch (error) {
  console.log('error login',props.email,props.password);
  alert(error.response.data.message)
}
```

};

```html
export const setAsyncStorage = async (key, value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(`${key}`, `${value}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

=============== update 2=========================

so i've tried change id value in login function into string like this

```
const login = async () => {
try {
  let response = await axios.post(`${url}/users/login`, {
    email: props.email,
    password: props.password,
  });
  let loginData = response.data;
  console.log(loginData,'sukses login')
  setAsyncStorage('token',loginData.token)
  loginData.name === null ? setAsyncStorage('name', 'pengguna') : setAsyncStorage('name',loginData.name)
  setAsyncStorage('role', loginData.role)
  setAsyncStorage('id', loginData.id.toString())

  props.navigation.navigate("Artikel",{
    id:loginData.id,
    token:loginData.token,
    name:loginData.name
  })

} catch (error) {
  console.log('error login',props.email,props.password);
  alert(error.response.data.message)
}
```

};

============================
and here is the full code in my profile screen page, so i've tried using setTimeout to console.log(id) and run function to get user id, but still no luck

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, Text, View, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

import ProfileForms from './ProfileForms/ProfileForms'
import axios from 'axios'
import styles from "../styles";
import {url} from '../config/variables'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function ProfileScreen (){
  const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [id, setId] = useState(null)
  const [name, setName] = useState(null)
 
  async function getAsyncStorageId(){
    const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id')
    console.log('user id from AsyncStorage is: ',userId)
    await setId(userId)
    console.log('state hooks id : ',id)
  }

  async function getUserData(){
    console.log('getting userr data')
    try {
      let result = await axios.get(`${url}/users/${id}`)
      console.log(result.data)
      setName(result.data.name)
      setIsLoading(false)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  function test(){
    getAsyncStorageId()
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(id)
      getUserData()
    }, 5000);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    test()
  },[])

  return( 
    <ScrollView>
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS == "ios"? "padding" : "height"} style={styles.container}>
      {
        !isLoading &&
        <ProfileForms
          id={id}
          name={name}
          setName={setName}
        />
      }
      {
        isLoading &&
        <View>
          <Text>Loading</Text>
        </View>
      }
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

=============== update again =================

so i created a variable and i replace my id state with this variable and it works.. for the moment i think im gonna stick with this

```
let desperateId = null



async function getAsyncStorageId(){
  const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id')
  console.log('user id from AsyncStorage is: ',userId)
  desperateId=userId
  await setId(userId)
  console.log('state hooks id : ',id)
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the code where you set `id` in `AsyncStorage` ?

Comment: `setId` is asynchronous so it's normal that `id` is logged null just after calling `setId`. just add `await` before `setId(userId)` and normally it should work

Comment: @MahdiN i've tried that but the value still "null"

Comment: @MahdiN but when i edit my code (anywhere), the apps automatically refresh and somehow the value changed, but when i rebuild and go to profilescreen directly it wont change

Comment: I think that it's because of fast refresh, when you change your code the emulator is refreshed with new code. I'm sure that the problem is with asynchronous `setId`, try to console log id after calling `getAsyncStorageId` in useEffect and add await to getAsyncStorageId

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only store the `string` type in `AsyncStorage`. Try setting the value like this.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('id', '5')
```

In your case, it would be like this

```
setAsyncStorage('id', JSON.stringify(loginData.id))
```

Update:

```
const [id, setId] = useState('')
```

Comment: my setAsyncStorage automatically change number to string

Comment: the problem is i cant changen my state hooks with the value of async storage

Comment: did you manage to fix this ?